# Data don't show for different id from models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a survey app. But, when I create 2 surveys, the questions from the second question doesn't appear in the template. There are 3 question for the survey 1 (which works great) and 2 questions for survey 2 (which don't show on template).

Here are my models:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_survey_set")

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

    def user_data(self):
        p = self.user
        return p.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.name)

def validate_list(value):
    values = value.split('')
    if len(values) < 2:
        raise ValidationError("A resposta precisa ter mais de um item")
    pass

class Question(models.Model):
    TEXT = 'text'
    RADIO = 'radio'
    SELECT = 'select'
    SELECT_MULTIPLE = 'select-multiple'
    INTEGER = 'integer'

    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        (TEXT, 'text'),
        (RADIO, 'radio'),
        (SELECT, 'select'),
        (SELECT_MULTIPLE, 'Select Multiple'),
        (INTEGER, 'integer'),
    )


    text = models.TextField()
    required = models.BooleanField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=QUESTION_TYPES, default=TEXT)
    choices = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,
                               help_text='if the question type is "radio", "select" or "select multiple" provide a comma separated list for this question')
```

This is the view:

```
def SurveyDetail(request, id):
        survey = Survey.objects.get(id=id)
        category_items = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey)
        categories = [c.name for c in category_items]
        print 'categories for this survey:'
        print categories
        if request.method == 'POST':
                form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey)
                if form.is_valid():
                        response = form.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("/confirm/%s" % response.interview_uuid)
        else:
                form = ResponseForm(survey=survey)
                print form
                # TODO sort by category
        return render(request, 'survey.html', {'response_form': form, 'survey': survey, 'categories': categories})
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Already got the problem.

The new survey needs a new category to show the questions in the template.